# FileReader methods read() and read(char[]) in JAVA

Tags: java, file, while-loop, filereader, java-io

I am reading all the characters from a file with a `FileReader` object by using the `read()` and `read(char[] ch)` methods. But when I try to use both these methods I get the output only for one.

Here is my code snippet:

```
class FR
{
    void filereader() throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File("abc.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        char[] ch = new char[(int)f.length()];
        fr.read(ch);
        for (char ch1 : ch)
        {
            System.out.print(ch1);
        }
        System.out.println("\n*********************************");
        int i = fr.read();
        while(i != -1)
        {
            System.out.print((char)i);
            i = fr.read();
        }
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain why the `while` part is not executing?

Comment: What are the contents of `abc.txt`?

Comment: Just My name, My college, My course all in separate lines.

Comment: Note: `f.length()` is the length in bytes not chars. If you have multi-byte chars, the actual length of chars will be less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform:

```
char[] ch = new char[(int)f.length()];
fr.read(ch);
```

You are effectively reading **the entire file**.
After that every call to `read` will return `-1` since it's the end of the file:

> Returns the number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

You can see an example of usage with input/output [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filereader_class.htm).

If you want to read the file word-by-word or line-by-line you might want to look at [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your `fr.read(ch)` call is reading th whole file.
Calling `fr.read()` after this will detect `EOF` and not return any character.

You will see different behaviour when changing the order of the reading sections of your code.

You also should check the number of characters read by your `fr.read(ch)` call. This should have given the clue on this.

Comment: Grt!!! That helped a lot. So i need to add a new `FileReader` object for `while` block to execute.....